# Printing an array sideways (transpose) only using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

I'm trying to write a method called "transpose" which prints a 2D array "sideways" (meaning its columns are its lines and its lines are its columns) only using pointers, even int i as an index is unaccepted.
Cell 0 of each array contains its size and at the end of the big array there is a Null address.

Example:

```
int A[] = { 5,-5,14,5,2 };
int B[] = { 3,6,11 };
int C[] = { 4,1,-3,4 };
int D[] = { 6,2,7,1,8,2 };
int E[] = { 2,15 };
int F[] = { 3,4,-2 };
int *All[] = { A,B,C,D,E,F,NULL };
```

Method needs to print:

```
-5    6   1   2   15   4
14   11  -3   7       -2
 5        4   1     
 2            8     
              2
```

(note: we only print the array from cell 1 because we don't print the size)

This is my progress so far:

I've made a method which returns the address of the longest array:

```
int * getMax(int **All) 
      {
          int * max = (*All);
          while (*All != NULL)
          {
              if ((*All)[0] > max[0]) 
              {
                  max = (*All);
          }
          *All++;
      }
      return max;
      }
```

This will return the address of D and then I can access the value 6 (which is the biggest line) by :

```
void transpose(int **All) 
     {
         int * lines = getMax(All);
         int * m = lines + lines[0];
         lines++;
         while (lines != m) 
         {
                 lines++;
         }
     }
```

This will run an outer loop 5 times so we can print 5 lines.
Then we can make an inner loop for the amount of columns and we can use the keyword NULL as a stopping point

```
void transpose(int **All) 
     {
         int * lines = getMax(All);
         int * m = lines + lines[0];
         lines++;
         while (lines != m) 
         {
             int ** arr = All;
             while (*arr != NULL) 
             {
                *arr++;
         }
                 lines++;
     }
```

I'm running into a problem that is the other arrays are less then 5 (max line length) how will I make sure that it prints a blank space and not goes out of bounds.

Comment: I wrote a completely different working solution. I can share that if you want.

Comment: Yes Please @Soumen

Comment: Dones anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your concern:

> problem … is the other arrays are less then 5 (max line length) how will I make sure that it prints a blank space and not goes out of bounds (?)

The easiest way is, precisely, checking (when printing) that the actual row is less than the number of elements.

Consider this alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// I don't care WHICH one is the longest
int find_longest(int **ppi)
//                   ^^^^^ this is NOT a 2D array... 
{
    int longest = 0;
    if ( ppi )
    {
        while (*ppi)
        {
            if ( (*ppi)[0] > longest )
            {
                longest = (*ppi)[0];
            }
            ++ppi;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

void print_transposed(int **ppi)
{
    int rows_to_be_printed = find_longest(ppi);

    for (int row = 1; row < rows_to_be_printed; ++row)
    {
        for (int i = 0; ppi[i]; ++i)
        {
            // the first element is the number of elements, so...
            if (ppi[i][0] > row)
            {
                printf("%4d", ppi[i][row]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("    ");   
            }
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int main()
{
    // The first element is the number of elements, including itself (odd…)
    int A[] = { 5,-5,14,5,2 };
    int B[] = { 3,6,11 };
    int C[] = { 4,1,-3,4 };
    int D[] = { 6,2,7,1,8,2 };
    int E[] = { 2,15 };
    int F[] = { 3,4,-2 };
    // Please note that this is NOT a 2D array, it's an array of pointers
    int *All[] = { A,B,C,D,E,F,NULL};

    print_transposed(All);
}
```

This would print out:

```
  -5   6   1   2  15   4
  14  11  -3   7      -2
   5       4   1        
   2           8        
               2
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to consider one of the constrains of the assignment:

> only use pointers meaning you are not allowed to declare an integer value

This is viable, it just makes the code uglier:

```
int *find_longest(int **ppi)
{
    int *longest = NULL;
    if ( ppi )
    {
        longest = *ppi;
        while (*ppi)
        {
            if ( **ppi > *longest )
            {
                longest = *ppi;
            }
            ++ppi;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

void print_transposed(int **ppi)
{
    int *longest = find_longest(ppi);
    if ( longest )
    {
        int *end_of_longest = longest + *longest;
        for (int *row = longest + 1; row != end_of_longest; ++row)
        {
            for (int **ppj = ppi; *ppj; ++ppj)
            {
                if ( (*ppj)[0] > row - longest)
                {
                    printf("%4d", (*ppj)[row - longest]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("    ");   
                }
            }
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the question is to only use pointers meaning you are not allowed to declare an integer value

Comment: consider instead of using arr[i], i++ <==> use *(*arr0), (*arr)++

Comment: @MicaelIllos Could [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gNTmZ7i7vQoiJx89) be acceptable or kind of a cheat?

Comment: YES that exactly what I'm looking for! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Another option to transpose the arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    int A[] = { 5,-5,14,5,2 };
    int B[] = { 3,6,11 };
    int C[] = { 4,1,-3,4 };
    int D[] = { 6,2,7,1,8,2 };
    int E[] = { 2,15 };
    int F[] = { 3,4,-2 };
    int *All[] = { A,B,C,D,E,F,NULL };
    int **line = All;//used to iterate through arrays A, B, C...
    int *col = *line;//points to an array and then an element in array
    int *repeat = *line;//flag to continue do/while
    int *astart = *line;//set to first array first element ex A[0]
    int *acurr = astart;//set to track do/while element ex A[1], A[2]...

    do {
        line = All;//reset line for each iteration
        repeat = NULL;//set so as to stop loop if no more elements
        while ( line && *line) {//loop to sentinel NULL
            if ( *line == astart) {//at the first array in this example A[]
                ++acurr;//advance current pointer to next element ex A[1], A[2]...
            }
            col = *line;//set col to point to each array A[0], B[0], C[0]...
            col += acurr - astart;//advance col to each element in each array A[n]...
            if ( **line > ( acurr - astart)) {//if value at **line ( ex A[0]) greater than n
                printf ( "%-5d", *col);//print value
                if ( **line > ( acurr - astart) + 1) {//indicates are there more elements
                    repeat = col;//set so as to repeat do/while
                }
            }
            else {
                printf ( "     ");//print spaces
            }
            line++;//next array A[0], B[0], C[0]...
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    } while ( repeat);//loop exits it repeat == NULL

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
  int A[] = { 5,-5,14,5,2 };                                                    
  int B[] = { 3,6,11 };                                                         
  int C[] = { 4,1,-3,4 };                                                       
  int D[] = { 6,2,7,1,8,2 };                                                    
  int E[] = { 2,15 };                                                           
  int F[] = { 3,4,-2 };                                                         
  int *All[] = { A,B,C,D,E,F,NULL };                                            

  int index = 1;                                                                
  int rem   = 6;     // change this to a function which returns length of All[]                                                   

  while (rem > 0)                                                               
  {                                                                             
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)      // Here also change 6 with a function                                           
    {                                                                           
      int *arr = All[i];                                                        

      if (index < arr[0])                                                       
        printf("%-4d", arr[index]);                                             
      else                                                                      
      {                                                                         
        rem--;                                                                  
        printf("    ");                                                         
      }                                                                         
    }                                                                           

    index++;                                                                    
    printf("\n");                                                               
  }                                                                             

  return 0;                                                                     
}
```